# Convert Column To Field Order

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am importing an excel spreadsheet into access, and requesting the user to input wchich column holds a userid and phone.  Now on the access form, they will be string values, like A & R

I am trying to then convert the alpha value to a number value, but when I use this syntax it is not giving appropriate results.  Such as the below produces `@` when I would want it to produce `3` - what is the appropriate way in Access to convert Letters to Column Numbers

```
Sub Test()
Dim colletter As String
    colletter = "C"
    Debug.Print Chr(Val(colletter) + 64)
End Sub
```

Comment: in excel, this is a valid reference `range(Cells(3, "b")` or `columns("b").select`  ... so this would work `columns(colletter).select`   .... it may carry over to access

Comment: you could open excel from access and ask excel for column number .... `debug.Print columns("abc").column`  returns 731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close. You are going to want to use the ASC() function which returns the ASCII value of a character. When you subtract 64, it will get you the correct column index.

```
Sub Test()
Dim colletter As String
    colletter = "C"
    Debug.Print Asc(colletter) - 64
End Sub
```

*EDIT: I've added some controls for multiple letters and to make sure that the letters are upper case. This does, however, limit it to only having two letters, meaning column "ZZ" is your last column, but hopefully your user doesn't have more than 702 columns. :)

```
Sub Test()
Dim colLetter As String
Dim colNumber As Integer
Dim multiplier As Integer

colLetter = "AB"
multiplier = 0

'If there is more than one letter, that means it's gone through the whole alphabet
If Len(colLetter) > 1 Then
    multiplier = Asc(Left(UCase(colLetter), 1)) - 64
End If

colNumber = (multiplier * 26) + Asc(Right(UCase(colLetter), 1)) - 64
Debug.Print colNumber

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that allows any number of letters, such as "ZZZZ".  As you can tell, it is quite similar to the post by @BobtimusPrime.

```
Public Function RowLetterToNumber(ByVal RowLetter As String) As Integer
   If Len(RowLetter) > 1 Then
      RowLetterToNumber = RowLetterToNumber(Mid(RowLetter, 2))
      RowLetterToNumber = RowLetterToNumber + 26
   Else
      RowLetterToNumber = Asc(RowLetter) - 64
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but can't you simply use: `=COLUMN()`